# If I kill spring cloud task jar it is not reflecting in SCDF dashboard

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task

We triggered spring cloud task using SCDF and abnormally if i kill the running jar which triggered for SCDF. In SCDF Ui still it is running state is there any way we can get the failed status in SCDF